# How to dynamically change part of string's color with SpannableBuilder

Tags: android, spannablestring, spannable

I am formatting strings dynamically, as the following example from Android documentation:

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
```

Then I set values like this:

```
var text = getString(R.string.welcome_messages, username, mailCount)
```

How can I set the green color for **username** and red for **mailCount**?

I need it to work for multiple locales, too. So I can't just hardcoded positions myself.

**Previously I split this string into 4 parts and then could easily use `SpannableBuilder` to change colors.**

*HTML and CDATA are not appropriate. We need to keep the same strings for Android and iOS.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SpannableString` and `setSpan` based on your requirement.

```
<string name="welcome_message">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
```

---

```
void setSpannableTextWithColor(TextView view, int resourceId, String username, int userColor, int messageCount, int countColor) {
    String fulltext = getString(resourceId, username, messageCount);

    view.setText(fulltext, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    Spannable str = (Spannable) view.getText();

    int usernameIndex = fulltext.indexOf(username);
    str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(userColor), usernameIndex, usernameIndex + username.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    int countIndex = fulltext.indexOf(String.valueOf(messageCount));
    str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(countColor), countIndex, countIndex + String.valueOf(messageCount).length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

---

```
setSpannableTextWithColor(findViewById(R.id.text_view1), R.string.welcome_message, "Viktor Vostrikov", Color.GREEN, 122, Color.RED);
setSpannableTextWithColor(findViewById(R.id.text_view2), R.string.welcome_message, "Виктор Востриков", Color.GREEN, 2, Color.RED);
setSpannableTextWithColor(findViewById(R.id.text_view3), R.string.welcome_message, "فيكتور فوستريكوف", Color.GREEN, 2000, Color.RED);
```

**Output:**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

Declare string

```
<string name="string_formatted"><![CDATA[ Hello, <font color=#145A14> %1$s!</font> You have %2$d new messages]]></string>
```

In Activity

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.mytext);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.html_formatted,"XYZ", 5)));
```

Comment: Thanks for html answer. Sadly, I will edit my post, that I would like solution without CDATA, because IOS does not support that. We want same strings in iOS as well as android

Answer (score 1):

Using Jetpack **core-ktx**, you can write it succinctly as:

```
val s = "Beautiful City".toSpannable()

s[0..9] = ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN)
```